# How can I Split a text file into new files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a text file in the following format:

```
001|fileA
002|fileA
003|fileA
004|fileB
005|fileB
006|fileC
.
.
.
xxx|fileX
```

I need to split this file into the files corresponding to each "|". The names of new files like fileA ,fileB,fileC...fileX .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 awk -F\| '{ print $1 > $2 ; }' file
```

where

- `-F\|` tell awk to use `|` as separator, | need to be escaped.
- `> $2` redirect print to `$2`'s value.

in case of many ( > 10 ) files :

```
for x in $(awk -F\| '!a[$2]++ { print $2}' file)
do
    awk -F\| -v f="$x" '$2 == f { print $1}' file > "$x"
done
```

- first awk merely list uniq filename
- 52 files are OK, this might get slow if hundreds of files.

another alternative, provided field are "safe" to put in shell

```
awk -F\| '{printf "echo %s >> %s\n",$1,$2;}' file | bash
```

- be sure to delete fileX before, in case of re-run.

Comment: This code will work when there are not more than 10 files. Because of 52 files, it responds to "awk: too many output files 10"